# $0$ to the power of $0$ calculus limits

Tags: calculus, limits

If you take the limit of $x^0$ as $x$ approaches $0$ (from the right), you get that $0^0 = 1$. However, if you take the limit of $0^x$ as $x$ approaches $0$ (from the right), you get $0^0$ = $0$. What is wrong, and doesn't this break calculus?

Also, if you take the limit of $x^x$ as $x$ approaches $0$ (from the right), you get that $0^0 = 1$.

Comment: It just means that the multivariate function $(x, y) \mapsto x^y$ does not have a limit as $(x, y) \to (0, 0)$, and hence is not continuous at $(0, 0)$. Calculus does not assert that every function is continuous, so nothing is broken.

Comment: With regards to your first question, $x^0$ and $0^x$ are different functions, and so it's perfectly normal for them to have different limits at a point.

Comment: "What is wrong, and doesn't this break calculus?" Why should anything be wrong and why should this break anything?  $f(x)= x^0$ is a continuous function that is undefined at $x=0$ and $g(x)= 0^x$ is a continuous function that is undefined at $x=0$.  As they are both undefined at $x=0$ there is nothing wrong with them having different limits.  Or as @user854214 puts it well, $(x,y)\mapsto x^y$ has a point of discontinuiry at $(x,y)=(0,0)$, which is utterly fine. Even if one person chose to define $0^0=0$ and another as $0^0=1$ that'd be fine as that just means $0^x,x^0$ aren't both continuous.

Comment: If you think those are weird, just wait till you see [this one](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+exp%28-1%2Fx%29+**+%28-ln%28pi%29+*+x%29+as+x+-%3E+0).

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this lies in the function $f(x,y)=x^y$
simply put, this function is not continuous at (0,0), and in fact, you have just proven this! What you stated only seems to break calculus because we feel like any function involving basic arithmetic operations should be continuous everywhere, therefore taking limits should decide the values these functions hold. However, such is not always the case, and this is a nice example of that.

edit: I should say technically speaking it does not make sense to ask if $f(x,y)=x^y$ is continuous at (0,0) or not, because it is not even defined at (0,0). The right thing to say is that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)$ does not exist.

Let me add, another reason you might feel like this breaks calculus is because we are seeing a multivariable function where the limit as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ does not exist, but there are paths which approach zero where the limit does exist.

for example let $\gamma_1(t)=(0,t)$ then we see that $\lim_{(t)\to(0)}f(\gamma_1(t)))=0$
while if we let $\gamma_2(t)=(t,0)$ then we get $\lim_{(t)\to(0)}f(\gamma_2(t)))=1$
$\gamma_1(t)$ and $\gamma_2(t)$ are both paths which approach (0,0) however we see that both paths approach (0,0) and the limit of $f(x,y)$ does converge on both paths, but it converges to 2 different values. However this is relatively common for multivariable functions for which the limit at a point is not defined. In Fact it is the case that the limit at a point is defined if and only if, the limit is defined for any path approaching that point, and the limit of all paths agree on their values.
Another example of a function which fails at this is the function $g(x,y)=\frac{x}{y}$ it may be more intuitive that in this case the limit as $(x,y)$ approaches (0,0) is not defined, but its not hard to see that there are paths for which the limit is defined, and in fact for every real number, there is a path which converges to that number, and there are also paths which do not converge!

You may think of needing to converge to the same value on every path in multiple dimensions, as being a generalization of the left side limit needing to agree with the right side limit for functions of 1 variable.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything wrong here. If you're worried about some purported fagility of calculus, this doesn't break calculus because you are considering the limits as $x\to0^+$ of three different functions; in order, of:

- $f:(0,\infty)\to \Bbb R$, $f(x)=x^0$;
- $g:(0,\infty)\to\Bbb R$, $g(x)=0^x$;
- $h:(0,\infty)\to \Bbb R$, $h(x)=x^x$.